# Ссылка внутри ссылки

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть карточка. Когда щёлкаешь по ней, срабатывает роутер и редиректит на другую страницу. На карточке есть кнопка (иконка). При щелчке по ней должен происходить редирект на другую страницу (другой домен). К сожалению, при нажатии на любое место карточке, происходит редирект на исходный endpoint.

У меня получается конструкция: сылка в ссылке. Из-за этого работает только верхняя из них.

Описываю кейс: при нажатии на любое место карточки, кропе иконки, должен происходить редирект на `https://my-site.com`. При клике на иконку: `https://another-site.com`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <v-card
            width="344"
            height="480"
            class="custom-debug"
            :elevation="hover ? settings.hover_elevation : settings.elevation"
        >
            <a
                @click="xxx"
                class="custom-debug custom-nav-button"
            >


                // Some things here


                <v-container class="custom-debug d-flex justify-start">
                    <router-link
                        to="/"
                        class="custom-nav-button"
                    >
                        <v-btn
                            fab
                            small
                            class="custom-debug mx-2 d-flex justify-center"
                            style="background-color: #ffc72c"
                            :elevation="settings.elevation"
                            :disabled="course.certificate === null"
                        >
                            <a
                                class="custom-nav-button"
                                style="color: black"
                                href="http://yandex.ru"
                            >
                                <v-icon class="custom-nav-button">mdi-certificate</v-icon>
                            </a>
                        </v-btn>
                    </router-link>
                </v-container>
            </a>
        </v-card>
```

Comment: попробуйте на тэге `a` (вложенная сслыка) - запретить всплытие. `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Дмытрык как я должен указать его, если у меня нет метода?

Comment: Слушайте, походу заработало

Comment: Я понял суть... Если распишите ответ, особенно про всплытие и причины этого, то отмечу как правильный. Я ни разу пользовался до этого всплытием. Поэтому для меня это интересно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - обойтись без `<a>` внутри кнопки, навесив обработчик клика на нее саму:

```
<v-btn fab small
  class="custom-debug mx-2 d-flex justify-center"
  style="background-color: #ffc72c; color: black;"
  :elevation="settings.elevation"
  :disabled="course.certificate === null"
  @click.stop="window.location.assign('https://another-site.com')"
>
  <v-icon class="custom-nav-button">mdi-certificate</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Так будет возможность остановить распространение события, используя либо [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) в методе-обработчике, либо модификатор `stop` vue-атрибута `click` (как в примере выше) - оба варианта равнозначны.
Аналогичным способом (через бинд на атрибут события) можно назначить обработчик клика и элементу `v-card`. Этот способ в целом является "Vue way", он [предпочтителен](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-HTML).

Почитать про обработку событий в стиле Vue, можно [в официальной документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

---

Демо (смотреть желательно в Хроме - он показывает домен при наведении курсора на его заглушку 404):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

```css
.v-card { margin: 1rem; padding: 1rem; min-height: 64px; }
.v-btn { background: #ffc72c !important; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-card @click="window.location.assign('https://my-site.com')">
        <v-container>
          <v-btn fab small @click.stop="window.location.assign('https://another-site.com')">
            <v-icon class="custom-nav-button">mdi-certificate</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: в этом варианте все равно используется модификатор `stop`, что и есть `stopPropagation()`. Не вижу смысла в использовании кнопки

Comment: @Дмытрык, Не понял критицизма "все равно" в комменте. Использование `stopPropagation` нынче считается недостатком/хаком/плохим стилем? А про смысл использования кнопки - это к автору вопроса, пожалуйста (задачу не я придумал).

Comment: Не заметил, что это код автора. Я решил, что Ваше предложение заключается в изменении кода, с тэга `a` на `v-btn`

Comment: @Дмытрык, Тем не менее, спасибо за повод дополнить ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Где-то встречал рекомендацию в таких случаях использовать `object`:

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.outer > * {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<a href="data:text/plain,outer" class="outer">
  outer
  <object>
    <a href="data:text/plain,inner">inner</a>
  </object>
  outer
</a>
```

PS: IE не поддерживает ссылки на `data:`.

Comment: Не очень срубил, что тут происходит. Поясните, плиз

Comment: @hedgehogues, просто тег `object`.